# How do I create a sandbox for displaying un-sanitized HTML as a preview in a web application

Tags: html, iframe, sandbox

We have an ASP.Net application where users can enter raw HTML for the purpose of creating a "template" that is later printed to a PDF file. We are using Ace Code Editor to let the user enter HTML text. The HTML is then directly displayed below the editor as a preview.

This works very well as long as the HTML is correct. We do take care to strip out any `<script>` tags - so script injection is not an issue. However, if the user makes some mistakes in the HTML (like not closing a div or table or closing too many divs), the preview can mess up the page layout.

I thought about displaying the HTML in an iFrame - but I need the iFrame to re-size the height of the content so there are no vertical scrollbars.

Whats the best way to display HTML that was input by a user within a "sandbox" div so that it doesn't get corrupted by erroneous markup entered by the user?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an other way then an `<iframe>`.

- You can give the `<iframe>` a width of 100% and a auto height or something like that.
- style.css: `iframe { min-width: 100%; height: auto; }`
- You can also have a look [here](http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net). Is this what you are using right now, or the solution?

Comment: An iFrame won't resize dynamically if the height is auto. The example you have given is also using an iFrame of a fixed height - the vertical scroll bars appear on the side.

Comment: try to give it `height: [value]vh;`